# Scraping images from reddit

Tags: php, json

```
 <?php

 $reddit = 'pics';

 $url = "http://reddit.com/r/$reddit/.json?limit=100";

 $json = file_get_contents($url);
 $js = json_decode($json);

  foreach($js->data->children as $n) {

        if(preg_match('(jpg$|gif$|png$)', $n->data->url, $match)) {
            echo $n->data->url."</br>";
        }
  }
```

?>

I'm writing something to scrape the pictures from reddit. I have looked at a few other people's code who do this and the only part I cannot wrap my head around is this:

```
$js->data->children
```

What I believe it is doing is telling the foreach loop to look at the $js, and the data, and then the children of those arrays.

I don't have a solid understanding of this, can anyone explain it?

Comment: $js is an object, and one of its properties is data, which also points to an object. A property of the data object is $children, $children is an array. A good place to start learning about these things is http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Hmm, these links may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162191/scrape-full-image-src-with-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593873/how-do-i-scrape-full-sized-images-from-a-website

Comment: is a good way to think about this that

    $js->data->children

is unpacking each object as a string?